# A potentially dangerous Request.Form - EpiServer

Tags: c#, asp.net, episerver-6, dangerous-request

When quick-editing a page on episerver - it's detecting a potentially dangerous request from one of the textboxes. Now the content to this text box IS potentially dangerous, but I don't want to validate each request. I've followed the obvious instructions of adding `validateRequest="false"` to the pages node in web.config and have even added `ValidateRequest="false"` on the page that I'm running (default.aspx) but the browser still appears to be validating.

Can anyone advise? By the way - I've mentioned that it's episerver CMS because the edit page of default.aspx differs (visually) from the typical default.aspx (although the same file name is listed in the address box).

Comment: What's your question? You mentioned that adding the proper values to your page and/or web.config prevents the validation.

Comment: And it hasn't fixed it. OP edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

http://world.episerver.com/Articles/Items/EPiServer-CMS-60-now-supporting-ASPNET-40/

A problem with EpiServer CMS 6.0's compatibility with ASP .net 4.